# whoami bash error

Tags: bash, centos, centos7

tengo un pequeño problema en ***Centos 7*** con el comando `whoami` en un `script` para *bash* el código es el siguiente:

```
function comprobar_root(){

    if [[ "$(whoami)" != "root" ]];
        then
        echo -e "\e[91mERROR EJECUTA EN MODO ROOT\e[39m"
        exit
    else
        menu
        exit
    fi
}
```

El problema principal es que al poner `sudo ./programa.sh` me sale que lo ejecute en *modo root*, he probado también con `su - y` loguearme en *root* pero me sigue dando el problema en vez de saltar a la función menu me sale el `echo` y sale del `script`.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Comando `whoami` en Linux

El comando `whoami` se usa tanto en el sistema operativo ***Unix*** como en el sistema operativo ***Windows***.

- Básicamente es la concatenación de las cadenas `"who"`, `"am"`, `"i"`
  como `whoami`.
- Muestra el nombre de usuario del usuario actual cuando se invoca este
  comando.
- Es similar a ejecutar el comando ***id*** con las opciones `-un`.

Las primeras versiones se crearon en ***2.9 BSD*** como una forma conveniente para quién soy yo, el ***Berkeley Unix*** que controla la forma de imprimir solo la identidad del usuario conectado. La versión de ***GNU*** fue escrita por **Richard Mlynarik** y es parte de ***GNU Core Utilities (coreutils).***

Los comandos relacionados con el comando whoami son los siguientes:

1. **w -**  Muestra quién inició sesión y qué está haciendo.
2. **who** Informa qué usuarios han iniciado sesión en el sistema.

Answer (score 2):

Será porque el comando es whoami y no whomai